# What is the mathematically operation referred to where you put a matrix of lower dimension into a matrix of higher dimension

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have a vector $A = [a_1, a_2, a_3]$; now let's construct another vector $B =[A, 1]$

What is this process of putting a smaller matrix into a larger one generally referred to?

Embedding?

Comment: Its called putting a smaller matrix into a larger one. Seriously, I don't think there is a specific name for this operation.

Comment: Okay cause someone used embedding to describe this process I was just checking whether that is the correct terminology

Comment: Embedding seems good to me. You might want to wait for some other comments that might have other suggestions.

Comment: It certainly is an embedding, but a rather special case.

Comment: @Jason please elaborate!

Comment: The "true" definition of an embedding is a map $A\longrightarrow B\,:\,x\mapsto x$ where $A\subseteq B$. In practice, we use the term for any injective map that preserves some kind of structure. So if we are calling the injective map $f\,:\,X\longrightarrow Y$ an embedding we are in a way identifying $X$ with its image $f(X)\subseteq Y$. What map are we using here?